# How do I export my views from a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a number of views in my SQL Server database.

How do I export these as `CREATE VIEW` scripts?

I tried to right click the database - script database as - create to - new query editor window, but it doesn't show my my views (or tables even for that matter).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SSMS, if you right click the DB -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts... - that will take you through a wizard.

Answer (score 1):

You can run through the wizard and select your DB, then the views as AdaTheDev mentioned or you can right click on each query and generate a script directly.

I prefer another way, because always I edit the views to remove "not necessary script generated SQL syntax" (depends on the point of view :)).

Right click the view, Generate script, CREATE in, new window.
See screenshot below (sorry for german version, but should work anyway).

[image: Sample Export of 1 query]

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to right click the db - script database as - create to - new query editor window, but it doesn't show my my views (or tables even for that matter).

The purpose of the menu you mentioned is only to create the empty database, without any tables, views or anything else.
If you want to script anything beyond the empty database, you have to use the wizard already mentioned in [AdaTheDev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089775/6884).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you receive empty page because source of VIEW was encrypted or removed.

In older SQL editions there was a trick - after creating VIEW (SQL Server compiled it) developer could remove source of VIEW statement to protect it from "deassemblation". In current editions there is possibility to encrypt source of VIEW statement.